# Adding plots to a pdf file

Tags: python, matplotlib

My code reads all the text file in the folder, turns it into an array and plots a histogram of each data using a for cycle, pretty simple stuf, but I want to save all it returns, all the histograms into a single pdf file. I know the function:

```
plt.savefig('file.pdf')
```

works but since it's in a for cycle it will only save the last one, I mean it overwrites on it. Is there a function to add the other histograms or should I change the code?

Comment: String `'file.pfd'` is the file name. Your program has full control over it. Make iteration number a part of it (e.g., `'file123.pfd'`), and each plot will be saved into its own file.

Comment: You can combine multiple pdfs into one. See [Merge PDF files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444645/merge-pdf-files) and [Merging multiple pdf files into one pdf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17104926/pypdf-merging-multiple-pdf-files-into-one-pdf)

Comment: @Peter Wood I know, I just wanted to do it all at once.

Comment: @bajotupie I didn't know you knew. How could I?

Answer (score 2):

You essentially have two options.

**1. Create multiple pdf files, merge them afterwards**

- [Merge PDF files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444645/merge-pdf-files)
- [append page to existing pdf file using python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38128675/4124317)

**2. Write all plots directly to a single pdf file.**

- Example from the matplotlib page: http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/multipage_pdf.html
- [Output a Document (preferably a PDF) from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41275563/output-a-document-preferably-a-pdf-from-python)
- [why does no picture show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41769620/why-does-no-picture-show)

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to export the histograms to images with Matplotlib and add them to a PDF file with ReportLab. This is a workaround, but you can tailormade your PDF report with all the histograms.

Comment: post some export code how you would do it o validate the posting of the answer. End of review.